# MySQL get max(PRIMARY KEY) for each compound group

Tags: mysql, group-by

I've got the use case to version objects (identified by `objectOwnerId` and `objectId` group). I insert rows to `ledger` table with their respective hashes.
The order of the `ledger` table is identified by the compound PRIMARY KEY and its `timestamp` up to microsecond precision + additional 3 byte entropy at the end to prevent collisions (in case  multiple rows gets inserted at the same microsecond).

Once data is stored I need efficient way to get the latest hash for multiple objects at once. I've came up with a query (please see end of this post) which is built from sub-selects with JOIN and GROUP BY, but it's pretty complex I think and I am looking for ways to address my problem in a simpler (if possible) way.

Is there any way for improvement?

It would've been simpler if I have PRIMARY KEY which isn't COMPOUND, in which case I could pass the max() value upwards, however that's not the case. I was also thinking if I could merge my TIMESTAMP(6) - 7 bytes with BINARY(3) - 3 bytes and store it as BINARY(10), but wasn't sure if that's easily possible.

Please find the schema, test data and SELECT queries below.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `ledger` (
  `objectOwnerId` CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `objectId` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `objectHash` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `timestampAdditionalEntropy` BINARY(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`timestamp`, `timestampAdditionalEntropy`),
  UNIQUE(`objectHash`),
  INDEX(`objectId`(10))
);
```

Let's insert some values:

```
INSERT INTO ledger (objectOwnerId, objectId, objectHash, timestampAdditionalEntropy) VALUES ('owneraaaaa', 'ida', unhex(substring(sha1(random_bytes(16)), 1, 32)), random_bytes(3));
INSERT INTO ledger (objectOwnerId, objectId, objectHash, timestampAdditionalEntropy) VALUES ('owneraaaaa', 'ida', unhex(substring(sha1(random_bytes(16)), 1, 32)), random_bytes(3));

INSERT INTO ledger (objectOwnerId, objectId, objectHash, timestampAdditionalEntropy) VALUES ('owneraaaab', 'idb', unhex(substring(sha1(random_bytes(16)), 1, 32)), random_bytes(3));
INSERT INTO ledger (objectOwnerId, objectId, objectHash, timestampAdditionalEntropy) VALUES ('owneraaaab', 'idb', unhex(substring(sha1(random_bytes(16)), 1, 32)), random_bytes(3));
INSERT INTO ledger (objectOwnerId, objectId, objectHash, timestampAdditionalEntropy) VALUES ('owneraaaab', 'idb', unhex(substring(sha1(random_bytes(16)), 1, 32)), random_bytes(3));
```

We've got this dataset:

```
# objectOwnerId, objectId, objectHash, timestamp, HEX(CAST(timestampAdditionalEntropy AS CHAR(6) CHARACTER SET utf8))
#'owneraaaab', 'idb', 'A8D3B63EFC6C63FD996B8D1931FBF748', '2019-05-29 11:38:12.353521', '725E3D'
#'owneraaaab', 'idb', '9B7395F9EE2F2363BA89C7FBAEDDBB54', '2019-05-29 11:38:12.352524', '8B8162'
#'owneraaaab', 'idb', '80393C5FF4492342D073B5F8B3388EC2', '2019-05-29 11:38:12.351569', 'FEAA02'
#'owneraaaaa', 'ida', '0D84F725ACAC87838C34742CA00BBEF7', '2019-05-29 11:38:12.350648', '41E425'
#'owneraaaaa', 'ida', '9A82C936A25C4648BFB75B692850841B', '2019-05-29 11:38:12.349625', '470685'
```

returned by this query:

```
select objectOwnerId, objectId, HEX(CAST(objectHash AS CHAR(32) CHARACTER SET utf8)) as objectHash, timestamp, HEX(CAST(timestampAdditionalEntropy AS CHAR(6) CHARACTER SET utf8))
from ledger
order by timestamp desc, timestampAdditionalEntropy desc;
```

I need to get this:

```
# objectOwnerId, objectId, objectHash, timestamp, HEX(CAST(s.timestampAdditionalEntropy AS CHAR(6) CHARACTER SET utf8))
#owneraaaaa, ida, 0D84F725ACAC87838C34742CA00BBEF7, 2019-05-29 11:38:12.350648, 41E425
#owneraaaab, idb, A8D3B63EFC6C63FD996B8D1931FBF748, 2019-05-29 11:38:12.353521, 725E3D
```

which this query can return:

```
select s.objectOwnerId, s.objectId, HEX(CAST(objectHash AS CHAR(32) CHARACTER SET utf8)) as objectHash, s.timestamp, HEX(CAST(s.timestampAdditionalEntropy AS CHAR(6) CHARACTER SET utf8))   from (
    select s.objectOwnerId, s.objectId, s.timestamp, max(i.timestampAdditionalEntropy) as timestampAdditionalEntropy from (
        select objectOwnerId, objectId, max(timestamp) as timestamp
        from ledger where ((objectOwnerId = 'owneraaaaa' AND objectId = 'ida') OR (objectOwnerId = 'owneraaaab' AND objectId = 'idb'))
        group by objectOwnerId, objectId    
    ) s
    JOIN ledger i on i.objectOwnerId = s.objectOwnerId and i.objectId = s.objectId and i.timestamp = s.timestamp
    group by objectOwnerId, objectId, timestamp
) s
JOIN ledger i on i.objectOwnerId = s.objectOwnerId and i.objectId = s.objectId and i.timestamp = s.timestamp and i.timestampAdditionalEntropy = s.timestampAdditionalEntropy
```

Comment: For what goal is the `timestampAdditionalEntropy` column used. in general `Entropy` is meant for passwords security.. But storing Entropy like salts in a database is never really smart what if the attacker did get into the database by some SQL injection bug in your application or by a programming lauguage bug it still happens and downloaded the information.

Comment: Also which MySQL table engine are you using? If i understand your question correctly you are looking for a faster method of using `MAX()` or how to optimize your currect query so it runs faster.

Comment: The `timestampAdditionalEntropy` allows me to INSERT more than one value in a given microsecond. It's just 3 random bytes, nothing to do with a security, this is log-like, append-only table.

I am using InnoDB, but this is something I can change if needed.

So far I am happy with the performance, I am looking for a better / simpler ways to solve my problem: GET MAX(PRIMARY KEY) for each compound group. Coding is not always about performance, but as well as readability. I want my successor to have easier life. Thanks !

Comment: ok fair enough.. consider using a [self join to find the max](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/urufbDbpYEkYosqQyVHoTs/1) .. basically removes the `Using temporary; Using filesort. Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)` which are bad news on lows of records on the current table/indexes

Comment: to make that query fly even more add the index `KEY(objectOwnerId, objectId, timestamp)` see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/urufbDbpYEkYosqQyVHoTs/3)

Comment: Also to make a other suggestion if you have MySQL 5.7 you can make MySQL to calculate the hashes on runtime see [CREATE TABLE and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

Comment: I like the self join approach. I get the idea. In your example there is: `ledger1.timestamp < ledger2.timestamp`, but I am missing the `timestampAdditionalEntropy` column. Its order is not very important on the INSERT time, the microsecond precision is enough, but during SELECT time, this order needs to be predictable, so if there are 2 rows for the same `objectOwnerId`, `objectId` for a given `timestamp`, the `timestampAdditionalEntropy` shall decide which one to return first.

Comment: The read performance is important, but secondary topic, the primary is the storage size. This table will be growing to 50M+ records. Hence any index I will be adding needs to done with care. So far the `objectId` has pretty huge cardinality. I am running MySQL 8.0, I am using generated columns in many other caeses, however those hashes needs to be stored permanently. This is ledger requirement, once it is stamped the hash can't be regenerated and there are other hashes which are dependent on it. Thanks for your input a lot !

Comment: Finally this is what I came up with to remove the COMPOUND KEY and it's all complexity.. It's 10 bytes non-compound key, which represents similar (if not the same) values as my previous COMPOUND KEY:
`SELECT CONCAT(HEX(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()), HEX(MICROSECOND(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6))), HEX(RANDOM_BYTES(3))) as PRIMARY_KEY;`

This shall make it all easier if we have one BINARY(10) PRIMARY KEY? I hope...

Comment: *"the microsecond precision is enough, but during SELECT time, this order needs to be predictable,"* Yes i forgot to add `AND                                                                                                                              
   ledger1.timestampAdditionalEntropy < ledger2.timestampAdditionalEntropy` that would do the trick just fine when selecting.

Comment: *"Hence any index I will be adding needs to done with care. So far the objectId has pretty huge cardinality"* [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) is not really imporant for indexes [selectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity) is.. How you calculate [index selectivity](https://www.akadia.com/services/ora_index_selectivity.html)

Comment: I haven't said that they can't be stored, I've said that I don't want those values to be regenerated in case the dependent column changes. The whole concept would fail regardless if hash is recalculated or broken anyway, so you're actually right, I could easily use the `GENERATED ALWAYS` + `STORED`, instead of generating hashes on the client-side. 

Would it be fair to say that `GENERATED ALWAYS AS STORED` supplements the fact that the `DEFAULT` value for column can't be anything DYNAMIC?

Comment: i remove mine other comment about STORED generated columns accidentally, *"Would it be fair to say that GENERATED ALWAYS AS STORED supplements the fact that the DEFAULT value for column can't be anything DYNAMIC? "*  Correct as you also can't use `DEFAULT (SELECT 1)` for [example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uevEqjH8FviKsjmgZEFUts/1) I believe is allowed as optional feature by the more modern ANSI/ISO SQL standards but MySQL never supported it.